# Ruby extend NilClass

Tags: ruby, boolean, null

I am trying to extend Ruby's NilClass for an application so that any method calls will return nil (actually self, the new extended nil). The purpose is to avoid a lot of extra nil-checking logic such as, for example,

```
results = data.nil? nil : data.process()
output = results.nil? nil : results.format()
```

and replace it simply with

```
output = data.process().format()
```

which will return nil if anywhere along the chain a nil result got returned.

It's easy enough to get a class to respond to arbitrary messages:

```
class SuperNil
  def method_missing(sym, *args)
    return self
  end
end
```

Now, `supernil = SuperNil.new; supernil.anything` returns the object supernil. However, this isn't really a nil because it will evaluate to true. Will it work to somehow extend NilClass so that my object will evaluate to false? Where I run into trouble is that even after extending NilClass, I can't create an object of SuperNil. NilClass.new gives an error, and so does SuperNil.new.

Is it possible to create an object of a NilClass extension? Will it evaluate to false?

Answer (score 6):

Try:

```
class NilClass
  def hello
    'hello'
  end

  def method_missing *args
    self
  end
end

nil.hello #=> 'hello'
nil.non_existing_method #=> nil
```

This might be however a bad idea as `undefined method for nil` is one of the most useful exception - it is saying you got nil where you didn't expect it. Instead, you should specify all places where you know nil might occur - have a look at 'andand' gem, which does exactly what's needed:

```
data.nil? nil : data.process()

# is the same as
data && data.process()

# what justifies the name of the gem
data.andand.process()
```

Update:

There is a very simple reason why it is not possible to create a subclass of nil - NilClass does not allow creating new instances, its `new` method is undefined (you will have same issue with all unmutable classes like Fixnum, Symbol or TrueClass). So:

```
class SuperNil < NilClass
  def method_missing
    self
  end
end
```

wont raise any issues, but you won't be able to create any instances of this class.

Comment: Your caution I think is a great reason not to open NilClass: any other code (especially included modules) that might encounter nil will not raise the probably necessary exception. I can see this getting dangerous rather quickly. Something like extending would allow me to create an instance supernil that I could use separately from nil--even override Array#[] to return supernil instead of nil so I can churn data to my heart's content without worrying. I'm definitely going to get myself into trouble.

Comment: I have updated answer to state why you cannot inherit form NilClass - andand gem is the only way to go (well, you can write sth similar by your self, but what for if this is working just perfect?)

Answer (score 3):

Extending `NilClass` in your case won't help because when you write `nil` you can an instance of a `NilClass` and there is no way to override this. That means your class will never be used.

You need to modify the `NilClass` or a parent class. In Ruby everything is an object, including `nil`. You can then modify object to introduce some custom behavior.

This is the approach adopted by [ActiveSupport `#try` method](http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/NilClass.html#method-i-try).

```
def try(*a, &b)
  if a.empty? && block_given?
    yield self
  else
    __send__(*a, &b)
  end
end
```

that allows you to shorten

```
@person && @person.name
```

or

```
@person ? @person.name : nil
```

into

```
@person.try(:name)
```

My advice is to not abuse this technique. Sometimes writing less code is not necessarily a good thing.

Answer (score 2):

Have you considered just using helper methods?  For example, instead of

```
results = data.nil? nil : data.process()
output  = results.nil? nil : results.format(1,2)
```

you might write

```
results = execute(data, :process)
output  = execute(results, :format, 1, 2)
```

where

```
def execute(receiver, *args)
  return nil unless receiver
  receiver.send(*args)
end
```

Two examples:

```
a = [1,2,3]
b = nil
execute(a, :max)       # => 3
execute(b, :max)       # => nil

execute(a, :delete, 2) # => 2, a => [1,3]
execute(b, :delete, 2) # => nil
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use the [safe navigation operator](http://mitrev.net/ruby/2015/11/13/the-operator-in-ruby/) introduced in Ruby 2.3.0.

```
output = data&.process&.format
```

Similarly you could use [Hash#dig](http://ruby-doc.org/core-2.3.0_preview1/Hash.html#method-i-dig), also introduced in Ruby 2.3.0.

```
output = data.dig(:process, :format)
```